# Any documentation for Swiffy. How use function SetVariable and GetVariable from C#?

Tags: c#, api, google-swiffy

I want to use HTML5 instead of SWF in my NET Project.
So, I install Google Swiffy Extension and after I converted Action-Script project to HTML5.
But I don't know how to use to bind HTML5 with C#.
Before I used Shockwave Flash Component in NET , for example

```
axShockwaveFlash1.SetVariable("_level1.shellContainer.ENGINE.my_room_movieclips.block_mc._x", "-5000");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function stage.setFlashVars requires **a String**,like

```
stage.setFlashvars("callback=console.log&version=1&locale=en");
```

And the **SWF file** can get the parameters by

```
var flashVars = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
```

you will get a "flashvars" Object (JSON Format)

```
{"callback":"console.log","version":1,"locale":"en"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote just analog *SetVariable()* for swiffy in JS

```
var SetVariable = function(Variable ){
   stage.setFlashVars(Variable);    
}
```

Analog *GetVarriable()* I didn't find.

C# project calls SetVariable in component WebBrowser

```
Uri uri = new Uri(PathToSwiffy);
webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetVariable", new Object[]{"SetEx=100"});
```